# How can I incorporate Gradle into my existing project on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I have this structure below and wish to incorporate Gradle to my existing project in Eclipse. Using the Facebook SDK in my project because the Login button on the home screen.

I have two questions: the first is how to integrate Gradle, the second is the standard folders and libraries are correct (There's something telling me that the Facebook SDK folder should not be there). Accept any kind of suggestion.

Thanks!

*Note: I tried using Android Studio and IntelliJ to be my main IDE but was unable to add the Facebook SDK to my project (As both use the Gradle, and I tried to reproduce what I'm doing in Eclipse, I think it made it impossible addition)*

[image: Structure]

Comment: "the first is how to integrate Gradle" -- Eclipse does not know anything about how to build Gradle for Android projects at this time. Are you trying to still use Eclipse, but do some command-line builds with Gradle? Or what is your objective for employing Gradle in your Android project?

Comment: @CommonsWare First the fact that most libraries I use, also make use of Gradle as a repository. And the fact as it has been integrated with Android Studio, must be something interesting to follow. I see many projects using Gradle (or Maven) and I want to use too.

Answer (score 0):

First, add `build.gradle` for your project (and its dependencies).
[Gradle for Eclipse page](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/) may help.

Second, try to search for Facebook SDK for Gradle. For gradle it should be one .aar file, that you would declare in main app `build.gradle` as one-liner like

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
```